# Minimal VPS configuration for vibed?

Tags: d, vibed

What is minimal configuration of VPS for Vibed? It's look like that vibed's memory print is very small. But building of it can take much more RAM. So what is minimum?

Comment: Just build it on your development machine and rsync it over. Btw a common setup is also to deploy on [Heroku](http://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/vibed/deploy-on-heroku), were the maximal memory is 512 MB, but in general the requirements depend on your application. However in the most cases they are pretty low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to build and run the basic vibe-d application using 512MB of RAM. However, this dips down to about 256MB when using `dub build --build-mode=singleFile`. As @greenify said in his comment, the best option is to build on a development machine and copy the binary across to your server to be run. However, if you want to do all of the building on your VPS, then I would say 512MB of RAM as a good amount to have.

Comment: could you explain what `--build-mode=singleFile` do. by docs I do not understand when I should to use it.